# Maintaining collapse state when drawer opens and closes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently having troubles with the material-ui drawer (https://material-ui-next.com/ one)

When I open the mini variant, the collapse inside my menu resets (closes because of the "remount").
However I would like them to persist their current state (open/closed).

Does Anyone know a way to achieve this?

The drawer:

```
<Drawer type="permanent"
    classes={{paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose)}}
    open={this.state.open}>
    <div className={classNames(classes.drawerInner)}>
        <Navigation updateTitle={this.updateTitle}/>
    </div>
</Drawer>
```

The navigation component: https://pastebin.com/webdmLXp

Rendered with open collapse:

[image: Rendered with open collapse]

After clicking the burger button:

[image: After clicking the burger button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure Mr who I share my lastname with, you need to keep state of each `<MenuItem>`. Just add an `onClick` to each menuItem and toggle the state in your component. This does not really relate to `Material-ui`, but is more a general `React` question.